# iTunes AppleScript: query all playlists that contain a certain track

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

Working on a complex AppleScript for iTunes. One task is to accumulate a list of all playlists which contain a given track. I have this track object from somewhere else (a selection or whatever).

Currently, I've got a snippet something like this:

```
on containingPlaylists(theTrack)
    tell application "iTunes"
        set librarySource to the source named "Library"
        set candidateLists to every user playlist in librarySource
        set candidateId to (get id of theTrack)
        set matchLists to {}
        repeat with candidateList in candidateLists
                set matchTracks to (file tracks in candidateList whose id = candidateId)
                if (count of matchTracks) > 0 then
                        copy candidateList to end of matchLists
                end if
        end repeat
        return matchLists
    end tell
end containingPlaylists
```

This works but requires one Apple Event per playlist in the loop, which is expensive (perf) and throws away the intermediate results. What I'd RATHER do is something all in one query:

```
set matchLists to every playlist in librarySource whose file tracks contain theTrack
```

But this of course doesn't work (the particular error is "Handler only handles single objects." but not sure if that's insightful). I'm really just not sure if the language/app supports a query like this.

Can anyone confirm/deny/offer any insight? Thanks!

Comment: Your one-line query's logic is wrong: you need to use `database ID of <track[s]>` to check if two track references' data is the same. Structurally it's fine though; it's just that iTunes scripting model is old and gnarly and a bit crap at handling more complex queries. Still, I wouldn't worry too much about sending a few dozen AEs as that's nothing; it's when sending tens of thousands that AE overheads bite. If you don't need a list of track refs, use `exists` instead of `get` to reduce work, but iTunes' performance will alway crater when resolving queries on large libraries (50K+ tracks?).

Comment: @foo: Thanks. Can you help me construct such a query? (Simply substituting "database ID of theTrack" in this case has the same issue.) I'm looking for the result to be the list of playlists which contain the track (don't need the track refs back, just the list refs). I'm building up to a huge batch job where the AE overhead will be a big deal, I'd be happy to avoid it where possible. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried, but iTunes craps out each time; as I say, its ability to resolve multi-item specifiers is poor. To minimize AE load, you could play about with `tell app "iTunes" to get {database ID, id of container} of every track`, which will give you all tracks' data IDs plus the IDs of the playlists that contain them. Use `NS[Counted]Set` magic to strain out duplicate database IDs efficiently, use `NSDictionary` to map those to playlist IDs, then another `NSSet` to shake out duplicate IDs, and finally build new `playlist id <ID>` references from what's left.

Comment: I should say though: until you actually write some code and profile it, there's really no point speculating where the critical bottlenecks [might actually lie](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Besides, there's not enough general info on what the rest of your program does to know if this particular bit is even appropriate to the overall solution, never mind if its performance will noticable difference to the overall runtime.

Comment: Thanks @foo. Useful ideas. Not worried about premature optimization much, mostly using it as a learning opportunity about the way AS/iTunes works (and doesn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this (work on **iTunes** 11 and 12):

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTrack to item 1 of (get selection)
    return user playlists of theTrack
end tell
```

Updated --

In the **AppleScript** dictionary:

artwork n [inh. item] : a piece of art within a track | 
elements : contained by **tracks**. So `artworks of thisTrack` works

track n [inh. item] : playable audio source | 
elements : contains artworks; contained by **playlists**. So `playlists of thisTrack` works, you can use `user playlists of thisTrack`

In **iTunes.h** (ObjC scripting bridge):

@interface iTunesTrack : iTunesItem
- (SBElementArray *) artworks;
it's not possible because playlists is not in the SBElementArray's list.

But I do not know why there is a difference between the AppleScript dictionary and the iTunes.h file.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This does not appear to be in the dictionary-- did you discover this through any usefully shareable way of systematically prodding at the interface? (Because it's not in the dictionary I also can't get to it via the ObjC scripting bridge, or don't think I can. Is there a better dictionary file somewhere out there?)

Answer (score 1):

I too wish a whose clause like that could be used. But alas. Someone else might come up with a better plan, but I'm pretty sure this is how I would find the playlists containing the selected track (it may be the most efficient):

```
set persisID to persistent ID of selection
set pp to playlists
set playListsWithIt to {}
repeat with p in pp
    set tt to (tracks of p whose persistent ID is persisID)
    if tt ≠ {} then set playListsWithIt to (playListsWithIt & (id of p))
end repeat
```

Then I can use those IDs for the next step. This includes, of course, playlists like "Recently Added", which may or may not be what you want; you'd have to put another step in there to 'filter' out such a result.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be the same execution outline - O(n) roundtrips in number of playlists. I'll steal some tricks in your syntax I didn't know.

Comment: Note: use `persistent ID` if you want a unique identifier for every single track object in your iTunes library that never, ever changes over the library's lifetime. Use `database ID` if you want to work out which track objects point to the same tune. Use `id` when you want something you can use to construct new by-ID references, e.g. `playlist id <ID>`.

Comment: Also, change your repeat loop to use `if exists (tracks of p whose database ID is dbID) then set end of playListsWithIt to (id of p)`. That should be rather more efficient. And if you don't want the result list to contain duplicate playlist IDs, then add `and id of p is not in playListsWithIt` to the conditional test as well.